# Making SlideShowExtender retrieve images from MS Access database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, asp.net-ajax

In my Microsoft access database I have a table called Picture and 3 fields: ID, Name, Image. I was wondering if it was possible to get all the images from the field 'Image'  and display them into SlideShowExtender.

Are there any examples or explanations to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your images are stored in the Access database, then you will first have to create a handler to display them. This handler will get the bytes our of the Image column based on the ID and send the bytes back to the browser as an image. See this for an example:

[Using ASHX files to retrieve DB images](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/5223/using-ashx-files-to-retrieve-db-images/)

With that in place you can display an image like this:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrl="~/DatabaseImagehandler.ashx?id=42" />
```

The SlideShowExtender expects a service to provide it with an array of slides, so this service should basically return this:

```
// Based on SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM Images
int count = 5;

// Create the array of slides
AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[] slides = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide[count];

// Put the URL and name for each image in the array
// Reader based on SELECT Id, Name FROM Images
int index = 0;
while(reader.Read()) {
  string id = reader["Id"].ToString();
  string name = reader["Name"].ToString();
  string.path = Server.MapPath("~/DatabaseImagehandler.ashx?id=" + id);

  // Create slide object with path set to point to the handler
  AjaxControlToolkit.Slide slide = new AjaxControlToolkit.Slide(path, name, "img" + id);
  slides[index] = slide;

  index++;
}

return slides;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use other slide show tools like "http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/" It is so simple to use

Comment: You can read my blog about how to display an image in web browser from a simple handler http://samiradel.wordpress.com/2011/08/03/how-to-display-image-byte-array-in-a-an-img-tag/